# Grep searching two words in a line

Tags: text-processing, grep

I've been trying to find a way to filter a line that has the word "lemon" and "rice" in it. I know how to find "lemon"  or "rice"  but not the two of them. They don't need to be next to the other, just one the same line of text.

Comment: To find all of the strings inside a file, you can run grep in FOR loop: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/462445/43233

Answer (score 76, accepted):

"Both on the same line" means "'rice' followed by random characters followed by 'lemon' or the other way around".

In regex that is `rice.*lemon` or `lemon.*rice`. You can combine that using a `|`:

```
grep -E 'rice.*lemon|lemon.*rice' some_file
```

If you want to use normal regex instead of extended ones (`-E`) you need a backslash before the `|`:

```
grep 'rice.*lemon\|lemon.*rice' some_file
```

For more words that quickly gets a bit lengthy and it's usually easier to use multiple calls of `grep`, for example:

```
grep rice some_file | grep lemon | grep chicken
```

Comment: Your last line is a *conjunction* not *disjunction* no?  To wit: the `grep rice` finds lines containing `rice`. It is fed into `grep lemon` which will only find lines containing lemon .. and so on.   Whereas the OP - as well as your prior answers - are allowing *any* of [rice|lemon|chicken]

Comment: Script version: http://askubuntu.com/a/879253/5696

Comment: @Florian Diesch - Mind explaining why `|` needs to be escaped in `grep`? Thanks!

Comment: @fugitive `egrep` uses extended regex where `|` is understood as OR logic. `grep` defaults to basic regex, where `\|` is OR

Comment: As stated in `grep`'s manpage, `egrep` is deprecated and should be replaced by `grep -E`. I took the freedom to edit the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 32):

You can pipe the output of first grep command to another grep command and that would match both the patterns. So, you can do something like:

```
grep <first_pattern> <file_name> | grep <second_pattern>
```

or,

```
cat <file_name> | grep <first_pattern> | grep <second_pattern>
```

#### Example:

Let's add some contents to our file:

```
$ echo "This line contains lemon." > test_grep.txt
$ echo "This line contains rice." >> test_grep.txt
$ echo "This line contains both lemon and rice." >> test_grep.txt
$ echo "This line doesn't contain any of them." >> test_grep.txt
$ echo "This line also contains both rice and lemon." >> test_grep.txt
```

What does the file contain:

```
$ cat test_grep.txt 
This line contains lemon.
This line contains rice.
This line contains both lemon and rice.
This line doesn't contain any of them.
This line also contains both rice and lemon.
```

Now, let's grep what we want:

```
$ grep rice test_grep.txt | grep lemon
This line contains both lemon and rice.
This line also contains both rice and lemon.
```

We only get the lines where both the patterns match. You can extend this and pipe the output to another grep command for further "AND" matches.

Answer (score 23):

Though the question asks for 'grep', I thought it might be helpful to post a simple 'awk' solution:

```
awk '/lemon/ && /rice/'
```

This can easily be extended with more words, or other boolean expressions besides 'and'.

Answer (score 11):

#### Another idea to finding the matches in any order is using:

grep with `-P` [(Perl-Compatibility)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_Compatible_Regular_Expressions) option and [positive lookahead regex `(?=(regex))`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```bsh
grep -P '(?=.*?lemon)(?=.*?rice)' infile
```

**or** you can use below, instead:

```bsh
grep -P '(?=.*?rice)(?=.*?lemon)' infile
```

- The `.*?` means matching any characters `.` that occurrences zero or more times `*` while they are optional followed by a pattern(`rice` or `lemon`). The `?` makes everything optional before it (means zero or one time of everything matched `.*`)

`(?=pattern)`: Positive Lookahead: The positive lookahead construct is a pair of parentheses, with the opening parenthesis followed by a question mark and an equals sign.

So this will return all lines with contains both `lemon` and `rice` in random order. Also this will avoid of using `|`s and doubled `grep`s.

---

External links:

<sub>[Advanced Grep Topics](http://caspar.bgsu.edu/%7Ecourses/Stats/Labs/Handouts/grepadvanced.htm) 

[Positive Lookahead – GREP for Designers](http://carijansen.com/2013/03/03/positive-lookahead-grep-for-designers/)</sub>

Answer (score 10):

This command returns matches for a line which has either foo or goo.

```
grep -e foo -e goo
```

This command return matches for lines which have both foo and goo in any order.

```
grep -e foo.*goo -e goo.*foo
```

Comment: This is mostly good, but also returns lines with only "foo" or "goo" in addition to "foo" and "goo".

Comment: Indeed.   "either foo or goo"  And, upon rereading, I see that the OP said ~"I know how to do OR I want to know how to do AND".  I will update the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If we admit that providing an answer that is not `grep` based is acceptable, like the above answer based on `awk`, I would propose a simple `perl` line like:

```
$ perl -ne 'print if /lemon/ and /rice/' my_text_file
```

The search can be ignoring case with some/all of the words like `/lemon/i and /rice/i`.
On most Unix/Linux machines perl is installed as well as awk anyway.

Comment: Refused!!! ;)  Because it make no sense.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a script to automate the grep piping solution:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

# Use filename if provided as environment variable, or "foo" as default
filename=${filename-foo}

grepand () {
# disable word splitting and globbing
IFS=
set -f
if [[ -n $1 ]]
then
grep -i "$1" ${filename} | filename="" grepand "${@:2}"
else
# If there are no arguments, assume last command in pipe and print everything
cat
fi
}

grepand "$@"
```

Comment: This should probably be implemented using a recursive function, instead of building a command string and `eval`ing it, which breaks easily

Comment: @muru Feel free to suggest an edit. I do appreciate the comment.

Comment: Editing it do that will be too much of a rewrite, so I won't do that. If you want to add it, here's what I imagine it should look like: http://paste.ubuntu.com/23915379/