# egrep command usage to find lines starting with one character that also contain some string

Tags: command-line, grep

Let's say I have a file which has some `ls -l` output:

```
waaa- foo.pdf
-bbb- foobar.pdf
-ccc- foobar
waaa- foobar
```

I'd like to get just the first line

```
waaa -foo.pdf
```

as the final result, and I'm trying:

```
egrep -E "^w" .file | egrep -E "*.pdf"
```

Is there any way to combine these two searches?

Comment: Did you actually get `ls` to display a [mode string](https://askubuntu.com/questions/397493/what-does-the-first-character-of-unix-mode-string-indicate) starting with `w`? As far as I know `w` only appears in other positions in a mode string (where it means "writable"). *It's totally fine if you didn't and this is just a regex example.* But if it also represents a real situation then it might be valuable to have additional answers showing alternatives to [parsing the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), like using `find` with the `-perm` and `-name` tests and the `-ls` action.

Comment: I don't think this is really a duplicate of [Grep searching two words in a line](https://askubuntu.com/questions/590384/grep-searching-two-words-in-a-line), which is about grepping for lines with two words *appearing anywhere, and in either order*. In this question, the line must begin in a specific way and end in a specific way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to write it like:

```
egrep "^w.*\.pdf$" filename
```

- Means started with `w` followed by any character and ended to `.pdf`.

for a logical "or" you can use `-e` switch:

```
egrep -e pattern1 -e pattern2
```

means all lines with `pattern1` or `pattern2`.

or as @steeldriver suggested, use extended regex "or":

```
egrep "(pattern1|pattern2)"
```

and as you know for extended regular expressions you have to use `egrep` and not `grep`, e.g:

```
egrep '(bbb|ccc)' # works fine for your file
grep '(bbb|ccc)' # doens't have any result
```

For an "and" you have to pipe it to another `egrep`:

```
grep pattern1 | grep pattern2
```

means all lines with both `pattern1` and `pattern2`.

or use another tools like `awk`:

```
awk '/pattern1/ && /pattern2/` filename
```

Comment: in this command ""egrep "^w.*\.pdf$" filename"  meaning of ( \ ) is "and"?

Comment: No, \  is used to escape the dot (`.`), dot `.` means any char and `\.` means exactly a dot `.`.

Comment: first command better, i dont have any knowladge awk yet:)

Comment: Note that you can use `|` as a simple logical OR in grep extended regular expression (ERE) syntax (or, equivalently, `\|` in BRE) e.g. `egrep '(pat|mat)'` and `grep '\(pat\|mat\)'` are both equivalent to `grep -e pat -e mat`

Comment: @steeldriver Yeah, however that's a part of regex and `-e` is a `grep` functionality itself right?

Comment: @Ravexina do we need -e option to your last edit which belongs to @steeldriver?

Comment: @solfish yes, because `|` is a part of extended regular  expression.  `egrep '(bbb|ccc)'` works fine on your file however : `grep '(bbb|ccc)'` doesn't have any result.

Comment: thnanks @Ravexina could you make edit pls:))